# Three classes have 60 students, half are sophomores. Pick three. What's the probability of 1 sophomore?

Tags: probability

I wonder if this question is poorly written, if I'm misinterpreting it, or if the teacher's wrong about the answer:
Situation: Mr. Kelly teaches three classes. Each class has 20 students. His first period class has 12 sophomores, his second period class has 8 sophomores, and his third period class has 20 sophomores. He randomly chooses one student from each class to participate in a competition. 
What is the probability that Mr. Kelly will choose only one sophomore to participate in the competition?

The teacher got 1/30. (I'm the tutor, not the teacher)

Comment: Well, what do you get?  Note that the third class is sure to produce a sophomore so you are just asking for the probability that neither of the other two do.

Comment: Note:  the question in the header is not at all the same as the question in the body of your post.  First of all, with your numbers there are $40$ sophomores, which is not half of $60$.  Secondly, the header question makes it sound as if we are choosing from the entire group of students, not one from each class.  Please clarify.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking; the question in the header is quite different from the question in the body.  Please edit for clarity.  When you do, also indicate your own efforts.  What do you think the answer is and why?

Comment: This seems like a really weird question...but the answer should be $\frac6{25}$